# Error when updating DataContext for Windows Phone 7 Pivot

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to dynamically switch the `DataContext` for my application when the selection of a `Pivot` item changes. Everything works as I want it to, however I keep getting errors in the debugger output window about data sources not being found from the ListBoxes present inside the PivotItems that are not the currently selected `PivotItem`.

For instance, let's say I have 2 PivotItems - PivotItem1 and PivotItem2 - each displaying one ListBox each - ListBox1 and ListBox2. Now, when PivotItem1 is active and displaying ListBox1, ListBox2 complains about its data source not being found, which is correct because the current `DataContext` does not contain the collection it is bound to. This is the error (I've added extra line breaks):

```
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 
'Entries' property not found on 'MyApp.ViewModels.CategoriesView' 
'MyApp.ViewModels.CategoriesView' (HashCode=79283607). 
BindingExpression: Path='Entries' 
DataItem='MyApp.ViewModels.CategoriesView' 
(HashCode=79283607); target element is 
'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox' (Name='ListBox2'); 
target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable')..
```

Similarly, when PivotItem2 is active, ListBox1 throws an error. I'm updating the `DataContext` within the `LoadingPivotItem` event of the Pivot, I've also tried doing this within the `LoadedPivotItem` event but get the same error.

Both collections implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and as I mentioned at the beginning, everything works, despite the error. I'd like to suppress the error somehow.

Here's the XAML for one the ListBoxes:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1"
         Margin="0,0,-12,0"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17"
                  Width="432">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryName}"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Margin="12,0,0,0"
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The other is identical, except "Categories" is replaced by "Entries" and "CategoryName" by "EntryName".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the action you're performing doesn't cause any errors in your application there will be an impact on the device as a whole while the Silverlight framework handles the binding errors.

Rather than having two different data models and changing them, why not have a single model which contains the "Categories" and "Entries" models but just set the one you're not displaying to be an empty collection (or whatever as appropriate). This would allow the bindings to still work but would prevent population of the list boxes you're not displaying.

Comment: That is a great idea. I'm curious whether this is known behavior though, that an attempt is made to load bindings of currently inactive UI elements?

Comment: @Praetorian I'd expect all bindings to be evaluated at the same time with a view to finding problems (raising binding errors) ASAP. It isn't safe to assume that bindings will be updated when the UI changes. It's much mrore common (expected?) for a datacontext to be set once and then changes handled in the viewmodel.